# Qt Creator Nothing happen when call a static library from an application

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Qt Creator Nothing happen when call a static library from an application.
I have these line of codes as my main.cpp main app file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include<src/main.cpp>
#include <src/john.cpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//John ll;
main2;

//    QApplication a2(argc, argv);
//    MainWindow w2;
//    w2.show();

//    MainWindow mainWindow;
//  //mainWindow.parseCmdLine();   //modified
//   // mainWindow.show();



   // return a2.exec();
//return 1;

}
```

and that's .Pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-12-08T05:51:54
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


INCLUDEPATH += ../application
LIBS += -L../application/release/ -lApplication
#TARGET = ../app17-exe # move executable one dire up
```

and my main2.cpp static library file is as below:

```
/*****************************************************************************
 *                                                                           *
 *  Elmer, A Finite Element Software for Multiphysical Problems              *
 *                                                                           *
 *  Copyright 1st April 1995 - , CSC - IT Center for Science Ltd., Finland    *
 *                                                                           *
 *  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or            *
 *  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License              *
 *  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2           *
 *  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.                   *
 *                                                                           *
 *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,          *
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of           *
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the            *
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.                             *
 *                                                                           *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License        *
 *  along with this program (in file fem/GPL-2); if not, write to the        *
 *  Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor,         *
 *  Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.                                              *
 *                                                                           *
 *****************************************************************************/

/*****************************************************************************
 *                                                                           *
 *  ElmerGUI main                                                            *
 *                                                                           *
 *****************************************************************************
 *                                                                           *
 *  Authors: Mikko Lyly, Juha Ruokolainen and Peter Råback                   *
 *  Email:   Juha.Ruokolainen@csc.fi                                         *
 *  Web:     http://www.csc.fi/elmer                                         *
 *  Address: CSC - IT Center for Science Ltd.                                 *
 *           Keilaranta 14                                                   *
 *           02101 Espoo, Finland                                            *
 *                                                                           *
 *  Original Date: 15 Mar 2008                                               *
 *                                                                           *
 *****************************************************************************/

//#include "mainwindow.h"
//#include <QApplication>
//#include<src/main.cpp>

//int main(int argc, char *argv[])
//{

//main2;
//    return a.exec();
//}

#include <QApplication>
//#include <iostream>
#include "mainwindow.h"



using namespace std;
/*
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

int main2(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MainWindow mainWindow2;
  //mainWindow.parseCmdLine();   //modified
    mainWindow2.showFullScreen();

#ifdef __APPLE__
// we'll change ENVIRONMENT so that the Elmer binaries and libraries
// hidden wihtin the application bundle will be correctly found

  char executablePath[MAXPATHLENGTH] = {0};
  uint32_t len = MAXPATHLENGTH;
  if(! _NSGetExecutablePath( (char*) executablePath, &len)){
    // remove executable name from path:
    *(strrchr(executablePath,'/'))='\0';
    char *oldValue = 0, *newValue = 0;

    oldValue = getenv("PATH");
    asprintf(&newValue, "%s/../bin:%s",executablePath,oldValue);
    setenv("PATH",newValue,1);
    free(newValue);

    oldValue = getenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");
    asprintf(&newValue,"%s/../lib:%s",executablePath,oldValue);
    setenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH",newValue,0);
    free(newValue);

    asprintf(&newValue,"%s/..",executablePath);        
    setenv("ELMER_HOME",newValue,0);
    free(newValue);

    asprintf(&newValue,"%s/../share/elmerpost",executablePath);        
    setenv("ELMER_POST_HOME",newValue,0);
    free(newValue);


#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("PATH = %s\nDYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=%s\nELMER_HOME=%s\n", 
       getenv("PATH"), 
       getenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"), 
       getenv("ELMER_HOME"));
#endif
  }    
#endif

  //========================================================================

  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QStringList argList = QCoreApplication::arguments();

  cout << "Usage:" << endl;

  if(argList.contains("-h") || argList.contains("--help")) {
    cout << "Usage:" << endl;
    cout << "  ElmerGUI [OPTION [FILE|DIR]]..." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Graphical user interface and mesh generator for Elmer" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Application options:" << endl;
    cout << " -h, --help       Show help options" << endl;
    cout << " -i <string>      Select input file" << endl;
    cout << " -o <string>      Select output dir" << endl;
    cout << " -nogui           Disable GUI" << endl;
    cout << " -e               Exit after saving" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  MainWindow mainWindow;
//mainWindow.parseCmdLine();   //modified
  mainWindow.showFullScreen();

  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

  printf("sss");
  char o;
  scanf("%c",o);


 //  return a.exec();

 // return app.exec();
  return 900;
}
*/
int main2(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//John ll;
//main2;

    QApplication a2(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w2;
    w2.show();

   // MainWindow mainWindow;
  //mainWindow.parseCmdLine();   //modified
   // mainWindow.show();



    return a2.exec();
//return 1;

}
```

and it's .pro file:

```
#==============================================================================
#
#      ElmerGUI: qmake project file for Unix, Win32, and MacX
#
#==============================================================================

include(../ElmerGUI.pri)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Target:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TARGET = Application
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += release

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Installation directory and files:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
target.path = $${ELMERGUI_HOME}
INSTALLS += target
edf.path = $${ELMERGUI_HOME}/edf
edf.files = edf/*
INSTALLS += edf
edf-extra.path = $${ELMERGUI_HOME}/edf-extra
edf-extra.files = edf-extra/*
INSTALLS += edf-extra

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compiler flags:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#CONFIG += warn_off

 #QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,$$(VTKHOME)/lib/vtk-5.2

#win32 {
 # QMAKE_LFLAGS += /NODEFAULTLIB:library
#}

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
#CONFIG += warn_off


 QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,$$(VTKHOME)/lib/vtk-5.2

win32 {
 QMAKE_LFLAGS += /NODEFAULTLIB:library
}

#win32 {
 #       TARGET = test
  #      LIBS += -lliba.lib \
   #             libb.lib
#
 #       CONFIG(release, debug|release){
  #              QMAKE_LFLAGS += /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt
   #     }
    #    CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
     #           QMAKE_LFLAGS += /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd
      #  }
#}


QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -g
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -g

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Directories:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEPENDPATH += . src forms plugins vtkpost cad twod
INCLUDEPATH += .
MOC_DIR = tmp
OBJECTS_DIR = tmp
RCC_DIR = tmp
UI_DIR = tmp
DESTDIR = .

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# QT:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
QT += opengl xml script
CONFIG += uitools
QT+=uitools
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MATC (see ../matc/README for more details):
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
contains(DEFINES, EG_MATC) {
   LIBPATH += ../matc/lib
   LIBS += -lmatc
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# NETGEN (see ../netgen/README for more details):
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INCLUDEPATH += ../netgen/libsrc/interface
LIBPATH += ../netgen/ngcore
LIBS += -lng

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# QWT:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
contains(DEFINES, EG_QWT) {
   INCLUDEPATH += $${QWT_INCLUDEPATH}
   LIBPATH += $${QWT_LIBPATH}
   LIBS += $${QWT_LIBS}
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# VTK:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
contains(DEFINES, EG_VTK) {
   INCLUDEPATH += $${VTK_INCLUDEPATH}
   LIBPATH += $${VTK_LIBPATH}
   LIBS += $${VTK_LIBS}
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OpenCASCADE:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
contains(DEFINES, EG_OCC) {
   contains(BITS, 64):  DEFINES += _OCC64

   unix: DEFINES += HAVE_CONFIG_H HAVE_IOSTREAM HAVE_FSTREAM HAVE_LIMITS_H
   win32: DEFINES += WNT CSFDB
   macx: DEFINED -= EG_OCC         # not supported at the moment

   INCLUDEPATH += $${OCC_INCLUDEPATH}
   LIBPATH += $${OCC_LIBPATH}
   LIBS += $${OCC_LIBS}
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PYTHONQT (see ../PythonQt/README for more details):
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
contains(DEFINES, EG_PYTHONQT) {
   INCLUDEPATH += $${PY_INCLUDEPATH} ../PythonQt/src
   LIBPATH += $${PY_LIBPATH} ../PythonQt/lib
   LIBS += $${PY_LIBS} -lPythonQt
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Process info query on win32:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
win32: LIBS += -lpsapi

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OpenGL GLU
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
unix:  LIBS += -lGLU
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Input files:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HEADERS += src/bodypropertyeditor.h \
           src/boundarydivision.h \
           src/boundarypropertyeditor.h \
           src/checkmpi.h \
           src/dynamiceditor.h \
           src/edfeditor.h \
           src/egini.h \
           src/generalsetup.h \
           src/glcontrol.h \
           src/glwidget.h \
           src/helpers.h \
           src/mainwindow.h \
           src/materiallibrary.h \
           src/maxlimits.h \
           src/meshcontrol.h \
           src/meshingthread.h \
           src/meshtype.h \
           src/meshutils.h \
           src/operation.h \
           src/parallel.h \
           src/projectio.h \
           src/sifgenerator.h \
           src/sifwindow.h \
           src/solverparameters.h \
           src/summaryeditor.h \
           plugins/egconvert.h \
           plugins/egdef.h \
           plugins/egmain.h \
           plugins/egmesh.h \
           plugins/egnative.h \
           plugins/egtypes.h \
           plugins/egutils.h \
           plugins/elmergrid_api.h \
           plugins/nglib_api.h \
           plugins/tetgen.h \
           plugins/tetlib_api.h \
           twod/renderarea.h \
           twod/twodview.h \
           twod/curveeditor.h \
    src/john.h

FORMS += forms/bodypropertyeditor.ui \
         forms/boundarydivision.ui \
         forms/boundarypropertyeditor.ui \
         forms/generalsetup.ui \
         forms/glcontrol.ui \
         forms/materiallibrary.ui \
         forms/meshcontrol.ui \
         forms/parallel.ui \
         forms/solverparameters.ui \
         forms/summaryeditor.ui

SOURCES += src/bodypropertyeditor.cpp \
           src/boundarydivision.cpp \
           src/boundarypropertyeditor.cpp \
           src/checkmpi.cpp \
           src/dynamiceditor.cpp \
           src/edfeditor.cpp \
           src/egini.cpp \
           src/generalsetup.cpp \
           src/glcontrol.cpp \
           src/glwidget.cpp \
           src/helpers.cpp \
           src/main.cpp \
           src/mainwindow.cpp \
           src/materiallibrary.cpp \
           src/maxlimits.cpp \
           src/meshcontrol.cpp \
           src/meshingthread.cpp \
           src/meshtype.cpp \
           src/meshutils.cpp \
           src/operation.cpp \
           src/parallel.cpp \
           src/projectio.cpp \
           src/sifgenerator.cpp \
           src/sifwindow.cpp \
           src/solverparameters.cpp \
           src/summaryeditor.cpp \
           plugins/egconvert.cpp \
           plugins/egmain.cpp \
           plugins/egmesh.cpp \
           plugins/egnative.cpp \
           plugins/egutils.cpp \
           plugins/elmergrid_api.cpp \
           plugins/nglib_api.cpp \
           plugins/tetlib_api.cpp \
           twod/renderarea.cpp \
           twod/twodview.cpp \
           twod/curveeditor.cpp \
    src/john.cpp

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Optional input files:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
contains(DEFINES, EG_QWT) {
   HEADERS += src/convergenceview.h
   SOURCES += src/convergenceview.cpp
}

contains(DEFINES, EG_VTK) {
   HEADERS += vtkpost/axes.h \
              vtkpost/featureedge.h \
              vtkpost/vtkpost.h \
              vtkpost/isosurface.h \
              vtkpost/isocontour.h \
              vtkpost/epmesh.h \
              vtkpost/colorbar.h \
              vtkpost/meshpoint.h \
              vtkpost/meshedge.h \
              vtkpost/surface.h \
              vtkpost/preferences.h \
              vtkpost/vector.h \
              vtkpost/readepfile.h \
              vtkpost/streamline.h \
              vtkpost/timestep.h \
              vtkpost/ecmaconsole.h \
              vtkpost/text.h

   FORMS += vtkpost/axes.ui \
            vtkpost/featureedge.ui \
            vtkpost/isosurface.ui \
            vtkpost/isocontour.ui \
            vtkpost/colorbar.ui \
            vtkpost/surface.ui \
            vtkpost/meshpoint.ui \
            vtkpost/meshedge.ui \
            vtkpost/preferences.ui \
            vtkpost/vector.ui \
            vtkpost/readepfile.ui \
            vtkpost/streamline.ui \
            vtkpost/timestep.ui \
            vtkpost/text.ui

   SOURCES += vtkpost/axes.cpp \
              vtkpost/featureedge.cpp \
              vtkpost/vtkpost.cpp \
              vtkpost/isosurface.cpp \
              vtkpost/isocontour.cpp \
              vtkpost/epmesh.cpp \
              vtkpost/colorbar.cpp \
              vtkpost/meshpoint.cpp \
              vtkpost/meshedge.cpp \
              vtkpost/surface.cpp \
              vtkpost/preferences.cpp \
              vtkpost/vector.cpp \
              vtkpost/readepfile.cpp \
              vtkpost/streamline.cpp \
              vtkpost/timestep.cpp \
              vtkpost/ecmaconsole.cpp \
              vtkpost/text.cpp

   contains(DEFINES, EG_MATC) {
      HEADERS += vtkpost/matc.h \
                 vtkpost/mc.h

      FORMS += vtkpost/matc.ui

      SOURCES += vtkpost/matc.cpp
   }
}

contains(DEFINES, EG_OCC) {
   HEADERS += cad/cadview.h \
              cad/cadpreferences.h

   FORMS += cad/cadpreferences.ui

   SOURCES += cad/cadview.cpp \
              cad/cadpreferences.cpp
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Resource files:
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESOURCES += ElmerGUI.qrc
win32: RC_FILE += ElmerGUI.rc
macx: RC_FILE = M3Dicon.icns

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# END OF FILE
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but nothing happen when I compile the project, No error appears but I think app could not call static lib.so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` in *main.cpp* should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return main2(argc, argv);
}
```

your line

```
main2;
```

do compiles fine, but does nothing.

Comment: Another question. Main2 has been called but not with its scope corresponding libraries such as it's mainwindow.CPP.means not static library include files.so what's the solution?